# first name last name relation type laravel

Tags: model, eloquent, relationship

Currently, I'm creating relations between my laravel models.
Taking into account the models like first_name and last_name, country can be the same for different users:

1. user A has first_name B and last_name C and country D
2. user E has first_name B and last_name C and country D
3. user F has first_name G and last_name C and country H

it looks correct to relate the models as below:

1. user hasOne firstName, last_name, country
2. firstName hasMany users, hasManyThrough last_names, hasManyThrough
   countries
3. lastName hasMany users, hasManyThrough first_names, hasManyThrough
   countries

Is this assumption correct as for me it looks like opening some convenient methods via Eloquent.

Comment: No, this isn't correct in any way. First of all why on earth you'd like to create separate models for `first name` `last name` instead of storing it in the `users` table and accessing through `User` model? Next, this could be `belongsToMany`, definitely not `hasOne`/`hasMany` and neither `hasManyThrough`. So reprhase your question and tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: don't judge it so rashly, please.I have my reasons to separate first and last names. I understand that this is not a common practice and can lead me to over-engineering in the end. but perhaps will not.

Comment: As for now I just want to keep them and user in separate tables. And thank you, you're right, I did use improper relations there.  So, let's skip that point on using separate models for last and first name, users, countries and try to modify relations:  1. user hasOne first_name, last_name, country.  2. first_name belongsToMany users, belongsToMany last_names, belongsToMany countries  3. last_name belongsToMany users, belongsToMany first_names, belongsToMany countries  Are these relations correct in a current set of conditions? This can look really simple, but I'm just learning the subject.

Comment: forgot to mention @JarekTkaczyk